# How to prevent iOS deep link from redirecting to App Store when app is already installed?

Tags: javascript, ios, deep-linking

I am trying to hit deep-link function from browser for Android & IOS application.
the function checks the application installed or not.
if application has installed they opened the app else they send me to Appstore or Playstore to download the app.

everything works fine with this code. and 100% working in android.
but in IOS the function check the application is not installed they redirect me to Appstore link. it is fine.
but the application is installed they opened the App and also redirect me to Appstore.

is there any way to solve this glitch?

here's the code..

```
async function checkAppInstalled() { 

 var deeplinkUrl = deeplink + "/" +declineworkdefaultcarid; 
 const iosFallbackUrl = "https://apps.apple.com/pk/app/prod/id16";

 try {
   await openDeepLink(deeplinkUrl);
 } catch (error) {
   window.location.href = iosFallbackUrl;
 }

}




function openDeepLink(deepLinkUrl) { 
 const iosFallbackUrl = "https://apps.apple.com/pk/app/prod/id16"; 
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  const anchor = document.createElement("a"); 
  anchor.href = deepLinkUrl;

  const clickHandler = () => {
    resolve();
  };

  const errorHandler = () => {
    reject(new Error("Deep link failed"));
    window.location.href = iosFallbackUrl;
  };

  anchor.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
  anchor.addEventListener("error", errorHandler);

  document.body.appendChild(anchor);
  anchor.click();

  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.removeChild(anchor);
    reject(new Error("Deep link timeout"));
    window.location.href = iosFallbackUrl;
  }, 3500); // Adjust the timeout duration as needed
  });

}



// main function 

const deeplinkfunc = async (e) => { 
const isAndroid = /Android/.test(navigator.userAgent); 
const isiOS = /iPhone|iPad|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent); var scheme;

var deeplinkUrl = deeplink + "/" + declineworkdefaultcarid;
var androidDeepLink = deeplink + "/" + declineworkdefaultcarid;


if (isAndroid) {

  scheme = androidDeepLink;

} else if (isiOS) {

  scheme = deeplinkUrl;

} else {
  //  this is for web application
  declinedServices();
  setdeclineuserwebstate(true);
}

const androidFallbackUrl = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=a1212";
const iosFallbackUrl = "https://apps.apple.com/pk/app/prod/id16";

if (isAndroid) {

  window.location.href = scheme;
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.href = androidFallbackUrl;
  }, 250);

} else if (isiOS) {

  checkAppInstalled();

} else {
  console.error("Unsupported device type");
}

};
```